# Fan fic where Harry is lord of Hogwarts?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

He's a lord of Hogwarts, descendant of all the founders, an Animagus, a Metamorphmagus, James and Lily are alive, he has a twin, and Ron and Dumbledore are traitors.

Comment: I would love to read this! Some more details would be helpful. Check out this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/112267) to asking a good story-identification. Also, be sure to check out the [help section](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) for any other questions you may have. Some details you can add, for example, is when you read it and where you read it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse. This guide might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly matching is [King of Magic](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12418957/1/King-of-Magic) by Radiant Arabian Knights.

> Harry learns about his inheritance and becomes King of Magical Britain. He has abilities which have been blocked. He also finds how Manipulative Dumbledore and the Weasley's are. Between Molly and Ginny giving his love potions to Ron and Hermione being paid money from HIS vault. Multi-Wives, Multi-Titles. Strong ultra-powerful grey Harry: Crossover Avengers/Percy Jackson/Thor/Harry

....

> "Well you have many titles Lord Potter. Here have a look", Ragnok says handing over the parchment

....

> Lord of the Most Ancient and Royal House of Gryffindor (UK)
>   Lord of the Most Ancient and Royal House of Ravenclaw (UK)
>   Lord of the Most Ancient and Royal House of Hufflepuff (UK)
>   Lord of the Most Ancient and Royal House of Slytherin (UK)

....

> Lord of Hogwarts

....

> Metamorphmagus: 98% Blocked

....

> "Yes they do. The Potter ring makes it so you will find your Animagus shape easier it also protects you from poisons and dangerous potions", Ragnok replies

It is indicated that Dumbledore is behind him being suppressed. However, James and Lily are stated to be dead (which is why he's being read their will) and every "twin" reference I've found is regarding his new wives (it's that sort of fanfic).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently read a Harry Potter fanfic that is a partial match to those requisites.

> [Basilisk-born](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10709411/1/Basilisk-born)  by Ebenbild
>
> Fifth year: After the Dementor attack, Harry is not returning to Hogwarts – is he? ! Instead of Harry, a snake moves into the lions' den. People won't know what hit them when Dumbledore's chess pawn Harry is lost in time…
>
> Manipulative Dumbledore, 'Slytherin!Harry', Time Travel! Harry Potter - Rated: T - English - Mystery/Adventure - Chapters: 64 - Words: 524,133 - Reviews: 4579 - Favs: 7,395 - Follows: 8,613 - Updated: Mar 24 - Published: Sep 22, 2014 - Harry P., Salazar S.

Lord of Hogwarts: . . . . . . . Yes

Descendant of all the founders: If you squint your eyes and look at it sideways, yes.

an Animagus: . . . . . . . . . . No.

a Metamorphmagus: . . . . . . . No.

James and Lily are alive: . . . Eventually, yes.

he has a twin: . . . . . . . . No.

Ron and Dumbledore are traitors: Yes but later Ron is partially forgiven although no more trusted.